# Groovy JsonBuilder, array inside an array

Tags: arrays, json, list, groovy

I need to build the following json using groovy's JsonBuilder().

```
[
  {
    "date": "2017-12-08",
    "dog": [
        {
            "name": "Joe",
            "age": "1"
        },
        {
            "name": "Bro",
            "age": "2"
        },
        {
            "name": "Doe",
            "age": "3"
        }       
    ] 
}
]
```

I cant get the array in the array, because of the date, it wants to always to put `date` not in the same level as dog array, but put it in { }, like:

```
[{
    {
    "date": "2017-12-08",
    },
    "dog": [
        {
            "name": "Joe",
            "age": "1"
        },
        {
            "name": "Bro",
            "age": "2"
        },
        {
            "name": "Doe",
            "age": "3"
        }       
    ] 
}
]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just stick the date alongside your list in the model:

```
import groovy.json.JsonBuilder
import groovy.transform.Canonical

@Canonical
class Dog {
    int age
    String name
}

@Canonical
class DogList {
    String date
    List<Dog> dog
}

def ark = [
    new DogList('2017-12-08', [
        new Dog(1, 'Joe'),
        new Dog(2, 'Bro'),
        new Dog(3, 'Doe')
    ])
]

def json = new JsonBuilder(ark).toPrettyString()
println json
```

prints:

```
[
    {
        "date": "2017-12-08",
        "dog": [
            {
                "age": 1,
                "name": "Joe"
            },
            {
                "age": 2,
                "name": "Bro"
            },
            {
                "age": 3,
                "name": "Doe"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Comment: Thanks, this works just like I needed. I was getting similar result to yours also, but I was having a unnecessary additional array wrapped around all of it when I used .collect().